# creating a span as color box inside a <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<p style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 24px;font-weight: normal;color: #848484;padding: 0;margin: 0;"><b>COLOR:</b> <span style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin:auto; display: inline_block; border: 1px solid gray; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; background: #FF0000 "></span> </p>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kDp/)

And I am trying to create the following effect:

[image]

Why isn't this showing up the color box in the span?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`display: inline_block;`

should be:

`display: inline-block;` (a hyphen instead of an underscore).

Always be sure to open up your browser's dev tools to easily find these types of mistakes. In Chrome, for example, inspecting the `<span>` element shows an "invalid property value" warning next to `display: inline_block;`